# ADF - Execute pipeline - Pass activity name as parameter

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a child pipeline that consists of few Databricks notebooks. I execute this pipeline with parent (master) pipeline using `Execute Pipeline` activity. I need to pass **name** of the master Execute Pipeline **activity** to the child pipeline.

I only found a way how to pass **master pipeline** name.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only solution I found is to create parameter for my child pipeline and then from the master pipeline pass value to this parameter. Value of the parameter is static string (no dynamic option available). I am generating those master pipelines programmatically, therefore I am able to include this parameter value automatically when generating this pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, apart from those in the system variables that you have already used, in the template language expression `@activity('ActivityName').name` cannot be evaluated because property `name` doesn't exist, available properties are

```
PipelineName, PipelineRunId, JobId, ActivityRunId, ExecutionStartTime, ExecutionEndTime, Status, Error, Output, ExecutionDetails, StatusCode, ExecutionStatus, Duration, RecoveryStatus
```

.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Fortunately I am generating that master pipeline programmatically, so I am able to create parameter with value of name of the activity. So that will be apparently the only solution.

Comment: Yeah, will wait one more day and then will post my solution. Thank you.